# How to change Y axis Label font size?

Tags: asp.net, fonts, size, label, mschart

I want to change the Y-axis label font size.

I tried...

```
AxisY LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" LabelAutoFitMinFontSize="5"
   LabelStyle Font="NanumGothic, 5pt"
```

and

```
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font.Size = 5;
```

but it doesn't work.
Its size cannot be modified even though I extend or minify it.

Please help me...!! :)

Answer (score 14):

You seem to have forgotten to change auto fit style for this axis. It default setting replaces your font size

```
Chart1.ChartAreas.["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelAutoFitStyle 
    = LabelAutoFitStyles.None;
Chart1.ChartAreas.["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font 
    = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 2.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
```

Answer (score 10):

You try this may be its working

```
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.TitleFont = new Font("your required font",uyour required size, FontStyle.your required style);
```

Set Title Color

Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.ForeColor = Color.Red;

Answer (score 6):

Instead of trying to alter the font size directly, assign the font with the style you require.  Eg:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas.["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 2.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
```

Depending on what you're doing you may also want to set IsLabelAutoFit to false as well.

Answer (score 1):

The secret is not in chartArea, but in Series:

```
Chart1.Series["SerieName"].Font = new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold);
```